# Hide the "Select All" checkbox in the Flow component Grid, when SelectionMode is MULTI (Vaadin 21)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin21

When you create a Grid component in Vaadin v21 and switch to multiselect mode, there is a "select all" checkbox on top. How can one disable that? There seem to be different default behaviours of the Grid and hence different solutions among Vaadin versions.

```
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>(Person.class, false);
grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.MULTI);
grid.setItems(personRepository.findAll());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to get the SlectionModel from the grid, to enable or disable the "Select All" checkbox:

```
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>(Person.class, false);
grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.MULTI);
((GridMultiSelectionModel<?>) grid.getSelectionModel())
      .setSelectAllCheckboxVisibility(
            GridMultiSelectionModel.SelectAllCheckboxVisibility.HIDDEN
      );
grid.setItems(personRepository.findAll());
```